# Wordpress set passive listener to active

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome-devtools, addeventlistener

I have a wordpress site where I'm getting the following error in the developer console using chrome:

```
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to 
target being treated as passive.
```

I have one javascript snippet where I set 4 listeners:

```
function moveDown(){                    
   const submenus = document.getElementsByClassName('sub-menu')  
   var navbar = document.getElementById("menu-1");
   var sub = this.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]
   var rect = sub.getBoundingClientRect();      
   navbar.style.marginBottom = rect.height + "px"       
}


function moveUp(event){  
   var navbar = document.getElementById("menu-1");
       navbar.style.marginBottom = 0    
}


(function(){
   var takeAction = document.getElementsByClassName('takeAction')[0] 
   var aboutUs = document.getElementsByClassName('aboutUs')[0] 


   aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseover', moveDown,{passive: false})
   takeAction.addEventListener('mouseover', moveDown,{passive: false})  

   aboutUs.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {moveUp(event)},{passive: false})
   takeAction.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {moveUp(event)},{passive: false})      


})()
```

Since I'm already setting `{passive:false}` on each listener, how do I fix this?

Comment: This [link](https://github.com/WICG/EventListenerOptions/blob/gh-pages/explainer.md) &  [this](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/beware-of-passive-event-listeners-2/) may be useful

Comment: add your html code too please

Comment: Please double check your code, may be this error occurred from other script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem has gone away.  seems like a wordpress thing but who knows

Comment: Did any real problem exists?  You can keep a check using a chrome-extension as well.

Comment: which chrome extension?